# Can me and my boyfriend play cross-platform?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So me and my boyfriend(long distance) wanted to play Minecraft together but it doesn't let us. I have a Mac and he has a Windows 10, I dont think that has to do with anything. Anyways we have tried everything to the point where I had to download a vpn, watched videos, whole bunch of things and we still cant play together. He said it was on my side that it was the firewall but its off.Help me please!!

We both have Java edition

Comment: Can both of you play on a (any) public server? If so, you should be able to set up a server and use it together.

Answer (score 1):

On Minecraft Java edition, the version that works on MacOS, Windows, and Linux, the best way to play together is with a server: [This one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381500) by my friend Darthvader1925 or [this one](https://minecrafthopper.net/help/setting-up-java-server/) by my friend SuperPowers04 & the MinecraftHopper team.  These do require Port forwarding or a tunneling service like [playit.gg](https://playit.gg) or [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com), to allow the other person to connect.  If you cannot do these things for yourself, or just want a simpler solution, you can also use [aternos](https://aternos.org/) or [Minehut](https://minehut.com/), who will do the hard part of hosting the server and leave you to just join and play!  If he is on Bedrock, then you must use Geyser, but that is beyond the scope of this Stack.

Happy crafting!

Comment: Hi, your aternos link has a colon at the end and its 404-ing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to double-check:

Your wifi, it might be weak and it might affect the connection

Platform, your version must be the same as your boyfriend's. So you might have Java and he might have Bedrock
If you HAVE checked all of this and it is still not working, I'm sorry I cannot be any use of help. Hopefully it works for you :)

Comment: They don't have Ps4, it said in the question. Also I don't think bad wifi would *prevent* them from playing, just slow it

Answer (score -2):

This is Minecraft Specialist Joseph Casey Speaking. Yes you can play cross platform. See if you can get the Xbox app on your mac, and see if your boyfriend can get the Xbox app on his windows. If you can, Friend each other on there and it should be good. IF that doesnt work, Comment on this post and I will look Further into it.